# How to specify x-axis in List when using Mathematicia and ListPlot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have imported a csv file into a list with this stmt:

```
data1 = Take[Import["D:\\_reports\\optim_5_60_b_2.csv", "CSV"],   5]
```

Which gives:

```
{{178, 8, 9, 1}, {152, 2, 8, 1}, {378, 8, 9, 2},
 {343, 3, 7.5`, 2}, {143, 3, 7.5`, 1}}
```

I would like to create a plot where the x-axis is based on the first field:

> 178,152,378,343,143,373,743,352

And the plot creates a line for each subsequent field, so the 2nd field is:

> 8,2,8,3,3,3,3,2

This would be the first line on the y-axis, the other y-axis values would be plotted in the same manner. I would like the first y-plot to be plotted in red, and the second in blue, and the third in green.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to plot a line instead of dots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And an alternative version:

```
data = {{178, 8, 9, 1}, {152, 2, 8, 1}, {378, 8, 9, 2},
   {343, 3, 7.5, 2}, {143, 3, 7.5, 1}};

x = data[[All, 1]];

ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[
  Sort[MapThread[Function[xpt, {xpt, #} & /@ #2][#1] &,
    {x, Rest /@ data}]]], PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green},
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {Min@x, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Similarly, but easier to read:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[
  Sort[Table[Map[{data[[i, 1]], #} &, Rest[data[[i]]]],
    {i, Length[data]}]]], PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green},
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {Min@x, Automatic}]
```

Comment: This was the actual problem I had, in the other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151575/how-to-plot-2-lines-and-spcify-that-the-first-column-in-list-is-the-x-axis I used Excel to modify the values used in the x-axis. The original post was at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144428/how-to-specify-x-axis-in-list-when-using-mathematicia-and-listplot I guess I did not ask the question correctly. Thanks a lot for your post, just what I needed.

Comment: Yes, they seemed to be quite similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
data1 = {{178, 8, 9, 1}, {152, 2, 8, 1}, {378, 8, 9, 2}, {343, 3, 7.5,
2}, {143, 3, 7.5, 1}};

tobeplotted =  With[{LocalX = data1[[All, 1]]}, 
   Transpose[{LocalX, #}] & /@ Transpose[data1[[All, 2 ;;]]]]

ListPlot[tobeplotted, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green},  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

I propose this:

```
dat = {{178, 8, 9, 1}, {152, 2, 8, 1}, {378, 8, 9, 2},
       {343, 3, 7.5`, 2}, {143, 3, 7.5`, 1}};

ListLinePlot[
 Thread[Thread@{#, {##2}} & @@@ Sort@dat],
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]