# How to plot 2 lines and spcify that the first column in list is the x-axis?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list that has 5 elements;

```
{{1, 6, 4.5}, {2, 7, 4.5}, {3, 5, 5}, {4, 8, 5}, {5, 9, 5}, {6, 10, 5}}
```

I would like to plot this so that the first column is the x-axis, and the other 2 columns would be plotted as lines. Like this:

Line 1 would be have these values 6, 7, 5, 8, 9, 10 and Line 2 would be built in the same manner.

I tired:

```
ListPlot[data3, Joined -> True, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"Test Number", "TS Index"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The resulting chart was not what I wanted.

How can I plot this as a 2 line plot? Also, what is the technical name for the numbers inside each element?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify x-axis in List when using Mathematicia and ListPlot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144428/how-to-specify-x-axis-in-list-when-using-mathematicia-and-listplot)

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = {{1,6,4.5},{2,7,4.5},{3,5,5},{4,8,5},{5,9,5},{6,10,5}}
line1 = lst[[All,{1,2}]]
line2 = lst[[All,{1,3}]]
ListPlot[{line1,line2},Joined->True,Mesh->All,AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 but this method only works if the x points are a basic range. Alternative version here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12161127/879601